# Converting Python code that reads in and manipulates CSV to R code

Tags: r, list, csv

Below is code in Python that reads in a CSV from a url and isolates the "ticker symbols" then converts it to a list. I am brand new to R and am hoping there is an easy, quick way to convert this python code to R before I get too deep into figuring it out myself.

```
# Read contents of csv link into string variable

cboe_csv_link = 'https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/'
output = requests.get(cboe_csv_link).text

# Find number of rows before string

find_str = "Available Weeklys - Exchange Traded Products (ETFs and ETNs)"
# Find index of search string in output
idx = output.find(find_str)
# Count number of newlines until search string is encountered
skiprows_val = output[:idx+len(find_str)].count("\n")

# Filter out rows and columns to isolate ticker symbols

cboe_csv = pd.read_csv(cboe_csv_link, skiprows=skiprows_val, usecols=[0], header=None)
tickers_df = cboe_csv[(cboe_csv[0] != 'Available Weeklys - Exchange Traded Products (ETFs and ETNs)')
                      & (cboe_csv[0] != 'Available Weeklys - Equity')]
# Convert dataframe column to list
tickers = tickers_df[0].tolist()
```

Comment: Boy.  That is an extra stupid file format. I would probably just download the file, and then use sed or awk to extract the relevant three blocks (each identified by their header) and read the respective chunks from the sed or awk stream with a normal csv reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem:

```
library(magrittr)

tickers = readLines("https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/") %>%  
  gsub(pattern='"', replacement="") %>% 
  subset(nzchar(.) & !grepl("Available Weekly|\\d+/\\d+/\\d+", .)) %>% 
  sub(pattern="([A-Z]+).+", replacement="\\1")

 #  [1] "AMLP"  "ARKF"  "ARKG"  "ARKK"  "ASHR"  "BRZU"  "DIA"   "DUST"  "EEM"  
 # [10] "EFA"   "EMB"   "ERX"   "EWH"   "EWJ"   "EWU"   "EWW"   "EWY"   "EWZ"  
 # [19] "FAS"   "FAZ"   "FEZ"   "FXE"   "FXI"   "FXY"   "GDX"   "GDXJ"  "GLD"  
 # [28] "HYG"   "IAU"   "IBB"   "ICLN"  "IEF"   "INDA"  "ITB"   "IVV"   "IWF"  
 # [37] "IWM"   "IYR"   "JDST"  "JETS"  "JNK"   "JNUG"  "KRE"   "KWEB"  "LABD"
 # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a translation of your Python code, but hopefully a fair interpretation.

```
cboe_csv_link <- "https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/"

rr <- readLines(cboe_csv_link)
ss <- c(grep("Available Weeklys", rr), length(rr))

l <- list()

for (i in 1:(length(ss)-1)) {
    l[[i]] <- read.csv(text=rr[(ss[i]+1):(ss[i+1]-1)], header=FALSE)
}
names(l) <- rr[head(ss, -1)]

lapply(l, head)

# $`Available Weeklys - Exchange Traded Products (ETFs and ETNs)`
#     V1                                V2
# 1 AMLP           ALPS ETF TR ALERIAN MLP
# 2 ARKF         ARK ETF TR FINTECH INNOVA
# 3 ARKG        ARK ETF TR GENOMIC REV ETF
# 4 ARKK         ARK ETF TR INNOVATION ETF
# 5 ASHR       DBX ETF TR XTRACK HRVST CSI
# 6 BRZU DIREXION SHS ETF TR BRZ BL 2X SHS
# 
# $`Available Weeklys - Equity`
#     V1                              V2
# 1   AA                  ALCOA CORP COM
# 2  AAL    AMERICAN AIRLS GROUP INC COM
# 3 AAOI APPLIED OPTOELECTRONICS INC COM
# 4 AAPL                   APPLE INC COM
# 5 ABBV                  ABBVIE INC COM
# 6  ABC      AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP COM
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different approach.  First we download the data to a file, say `weeklysmf.csv`.

```
> url <- "https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/"
> download.file(url, "weeklysmf.csv", quiet=TRUE)
>
```

We then use the fact that *all the lines you are interested in* have exactly two fields separated with a comma.  Using this `awk` invocation filters all lines with exactly two fields, using `,` as the field separator:

```
$ awk -F, 'NF==2 {print $0}' weeklysmf.csv |head        
"AMLP","ALPS ETF TR ALERIAN MLP"            
"ARKF","ARK ETF TR FINTECH INNOVA"        
"ARKG","ARK ETF TR GENOMIC REV ETF"     
"ARKK","ARK ETF TR INNOVATION ETF"
"ASHR","DBX ETF TR XTRACK HRVST CSI"
"BRZU","DIREXION SHS ETF TR BRZ BL 2X SHS"         
"DIA","SPDR DOW JONES INDL AVERAGE ET UT SER 1"
"DUST","DIREXION SHS ETF TR DAILY GOLD MINER"
"EEM","ISHARES TR MSCI EMG MKT ETF"         
"EFA","ISHARES TR MSCI EAFE ETF"            
$
```

We can use this with many of the csv readers in R which can read from a command (as R offers a connections interface where `pipe()` is an option as are `file()` and `url()`).  I like `data.table` so this becomes

```
> dat <- data.table::fread(cmd="awk -F, 'NF==2 {print $0}' weeklysmf.csv")
> dat
     AMLP            ALPS ETF TR ALERIAN MLP
  1: ARKF          ARK ETF TR FINTECH INNOVA
  2: ARKG         ARK ETF TR GENOMIC REV ETF
  3: ARKK          ARK ETF TR INNOVATION ETF
  4: ASHR        DBX ETF TR XTRACK HRVST CSI
  5: BRZU  DIREXION SHS ETF TR BRZ BL 2X SHS
 ---                                        
611:   YY          JOYY INC ADS REPSTG COM A
612:    Z      ZILLOW GROUP INC CL C CAP STK
613:   ZM ZOOM VIDEO COMMUNICATIONS INC CL A
614: ZNGA                     ZYNGA INC CL A
615:   ZS                    ZSCALER INC COM
>
```

(and `fread` can also return a `data.frame` if you prefer that, there is an option).